# How to customize build message set by Jenkins in Bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I'm using Bitbucket plugin with Jenkins to discover repositories and branches having Jenkinsfile and i would like to know if it's possible to configure the message that is attached by Jenkins to a commit at the end of a build.

```
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
```

For now i'm getting "This commit looks good" when build is ok, "This commit has test failures" when build is unstable, etc.
I tried to set the variable currentBuild.description hoping that it will be used to set the message on Bitbucket side, but it's not the case.

I also got the source code of the plugin, did a quick search and found these values look hard coded, unless i missed something:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/d80d434f36e43cab834765de03d83579869bfdda/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/bitbucket/BitbucketBuildStatusNotifications.java#L95

Any suggestion about how to implement this, except by submitting a PR there?